# Is there any way to return a message if the scope fails in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `User` model in my rails project, in the schema there is a field called `active` which represents if a user if active or not, I have added a scope like this

```
# app/models/user.rb
scope :active, -> { where active: true }
```

My use case is very simple, I want to find a user who is active like this:

```rb
user = User.active.find_by!(token: token)
```

The problem is I want to avoid using `begin` and `rescue` to catch the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error

What I want is to not throw this exception rather than that it should return a message like we do with

```rb
validates :xyz, message: "invalid input"
```

Is there any possible way to achieve this cause?

Comment: change `find_by!` to `find_by` -- will simply return a nil if the user is doesn't exist -- then you can return whatever you want

Comment: @dbugger the problem with that is i don't want to nest the block with if/else or begin/rescue, returning nil would lead me to check for 2 diff conditions like `if user .. elsif user.blank? else ..` there are also some more conditions which are applied so im just trying to refractor and reduce the code block

Comment: You want `find_by` to return a message, meaning you have to check for a message or a user and that's ok, but checking for a user or nil isn't?

Comment: so the main functionality is to find a User who is active and have a token equals something, so my check goes like this 
`user = User.active.find_by(token: "xyz")` 
then the conditions placed upon this are 
`if user current_user = user elsif !user&.active? puts "user not active" else puts "unauthroized" `
im trying to reduce this block to a simple if/else for now this is not something major but i was just wondering would there be a possible way to return "not active" directly from the scope so that i dont have to check it here

Comment: `User.active.find_by` will only return active users. Therefore, `user&.active?` will always be true when there was a user found. It feels to me like you want to load the user no matter if active or not to be able to check the `active?` flag. But that is not how scopes work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want catch exception — just use method `find_by`

Active Record methods with bang (`find_by!`, `save!`, `create!`, `first!` etc.) raise errors

```rb
user = User.active.find_by(username: username)

if user.present?
  # do something with user
else
  # do something else
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  What you're looking for is `rescue_from`

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html

and an exact example for you:
https://rubytutorial.io/rails-rescue_from/

Comment: `rescue_from` is severely under-rated. It's great!

Comment: @kwerle would this rescue run for the same Exception every time , even in the case for a different model? if yes is there a possible way to run it only for :active scope within the user model

Comment: As you can see, it is applied to the controller.  So if that controller has that exception then that's how it'll be handled.
As others have said, if you want to handle different reasons for the same not found issue differently in the same controller then you probably want to use the methods that avoid throwing that exception - and there are plenty.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly from one of your comments, you have 3 different cases:

1. User with the given token exists and is active: set `current_user = user`.
2. User with the given token exists, but is not active: write "user not active".
3. User with the given token does not exist: write "unauthorized".

We can't distinguish between 3 cases with a single check. We'll have to either use `if ... elsif ... else`, or use `if ... else ...` together with an exception and a rescue block.

Alternatively, think if it's ok to join all the error cases into one. Do we really care to distinguish between "user not active" and "unauthorized"?

```rb
current_user = User.active.find_by(token: token)
puts 'Inactive or unauthorized' if current_user.nil?
```

Comment: yes ideally that should be the case, what im trying to find is something similar to how we use validates in case the validation fails we get the error inside the object.errors.full_messages , i was just wondering is there a similar use case for scope? , in any case my scope fails i can get that the errors in a similar way.

Comment: It's not possible to do that because rails sends the full query to the db, not each scope separately. It asks the db "Is there's an active user with `token: token`" and the db says no. It doesn't answer if there's a user with that token that isn't active.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments to the post itself and an answer i have found one interesting thing. Here is the code you provided:

```
user = User.active.find_by(token: "xyz")
if user
    current_user = user
elsif !user&.active? 
    puts "user not active" 
else 
    puts "unauthroized"
end
```

Firstly if you use a scope for active - you dont need to check `elsif !user&.active?` because it will always be false, as the scope can only return a result with active users. That means you can't use **active** scope if you want to tell the if the user is inactive.
So that leaves us with regular **find_by**. In this case the better way to beautify your code is to create a helper function in your controller that will handle both the messages and setting the user. Something like this might work for you:

```
# your_controller.rb
# for this you will have to have templates with the names :unauthorized and :inactive
def index
    #...
    err = check_and_set_user(token)
    return render err if err
    #...
end

private
def check_and_set_user(token)
    user = User.find_by(token: "xyz")
    return "unauthorized" unless user
    return "inactive" unless user.active
    
    current_user = user
    nil
end
helper_method :check_and_set_user
```

Or you can even make it a separate **before_filter**, anyways you get the idea.